# Disable update of blocks locally with bitcoind cmdline option

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc

I'm using [blockchain2graph](https://github.com/straumat/blockchain2graph) tool to import the Bitcoin blockchain into Neo4j. It uses JSONRPC calls to read block data. For this, I have to have the `bitcoind` service running. Is it possible to disable the update of the blockchain while `bitcoind` is running?

I use the cmdline and I've tried `-proxy=127.0.0.1:1234` and `-debugexclude=proxy` options but it continuously outputs `connect() to 127.0.0.1:1234 failed after select(): Connection refused`. I don't want this output either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell bitcoind to have 0 connections using:

```
bitcoind -maxconnections=0
```